# Remove "Edit Chart" link from Plotly plot (Python)

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using Python to plot some graphics with the Plotly framework.

[image]

I would like to remove the Edit Chart link at the bottom-right. 
I tried different solutions, like

```
py.iplot(fig, filename=filename, show_link=False)
```

or adding the `&link=false` string at the end of the URL while embedding the plot in an HTML page, but the link is still there.