# “Edit Chart” doesn’t show in interactive graphs

Tags: python, pycharm, plotly, plotly-python

I’m plotting with plotly in PyCharm like this (not in a notebook, just a .py file):

```
from plotly.offline import plot    
import plotly.express as px

plot(px.line(x=[1,2,3],y=[3,4,5]))
```

It nicely opens the figure in web browser. However, I don’t see any “Edit Chart” link on the bottom right. How can I make it show that?

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: I see a problem in your code

Comment: @user1241241 I tested it again. It runs okey in my pycharm!

Comment: You don't need to use `from plotly.offline`

Comment: @rpanai You mean to use px.line(...).show()? That would be an alternative way to do it. But still there is no "Edit Chart" in the browser

Comment: Do you mind to add a reference to the "Edit chart" you mentioned? On Jupyter you just need `px.line(x=[1,2,3],y=[3,4,5])`

Comment: I see. Apparently in PyCharm you need the "plot" or "show". Regarding reference, here is a question that wants to do the opposite of what I want:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957873/remove-edit-chart-link-from-plotly-plot-python

You can see the "Edit Chart" I'm looking for in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet:

```
from plotly.offline import plot    
import plotly.express as px

graph = plot(px.line(x=[1,2,3],y=[3,4,5]), show_link=True)
graph.show()
```

Comment: But that's visible in the original code snippet too, right?

Comment: I updated the second to last line. @secluded, will that button work for you?

Comment: @ddcastrodd thanks, this is what I wanted! After editing the figure in chart studio, do you know if it's possible to directly go back to the original html figure with changes included or is exporting the edited figure the only option?

Comment: I do not think the original figure can be updated with the changes made in Chart Studio.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the  chart title, axis labels and trace names in the legend to the editable, then this should do the job

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.express as px

plot(px.line(x=[1,2,3],y=[3,4,5]), config={'editable':True})
```

If you want to make it editable on the click of a button, I guess you have to do that manually.